“por el que vagamos”
Meaning of …

Oh, por el que vagamos, buscando algún sol
Que nos dé la vida, que encienda nuestro amor

I get most of it, but the first phrase … “for this/it we wander”?  One machine translation gives “this is why we wander.”
From José María Purón’s paraphrase of “Little Voice Within”
The original lyric (English) doesn’t help; Purón’s paraphrase is very loose.

Machine translation for poetry? Tsk, tsk.

"El que" (la que, etc) is a relative pronoun meaning "the one which/that".
"Por" in this case (I think) means "through" or "along", as in e.g. "por la calle" == "along the street".
En este mundo oscuro // Oh, por el que vagamos --- In this dark world, oh the one through which we wander
Disclaimer, I am an intermediate learner.

That seems a very likely explanation.  I'll accept it if it's still the only one tomorrow.  "Intermediate" may be same or better than me.  I'm probably B1 on CEFR.  Tested only L-2/R2+ on ILR but that was before 17 months in Spain and two in Perú.

@WGroleau you should have provided the whole verse in your question...
